# Installing a minimal GUI + VNC

Tags: 10.04, server, gui, vnc

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 Server on my VPS and would like to install a minimal GUI onto this and allow VNC access to.

Please could someone outline the steps required to set this up so that I can VNC to my machine under a newly created user account.

**Create the user:**

```
useradd  -m -s /bin/bash -p password -d /home/usera userA
chown userA:users /home/usera
```

**Install the GUI**

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

**Setup VNC**

?

Comment: Does the --no-install-recommends flag work with apt-get?

Comment: @Toki I copied that line from a webpage - It doesn't work with aptitude but does run with apt-get

Comment: Great find, thanks! That will solve a bit of my own minimal-ubuntu problems, at least. :P

Comment: To show my gratitude, I'd like to help you. I can't help in setting up VNC, but I can help get a GUI even more minimal than ubuntu-desktop without recommended packages. Just tell me what applications you need.

Answer (score 2):

i would not recommend the regular desktop but openbox or fluxbox

Answer (score 1):

When you have the GUI installed, run sudo apt-get install vino to install remote desktop support. This is a little old, but it ought to explain how to configure it through ssh: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-266981.html